# Are all references live in scalars? even explicit ones?

Tags: perl, perlguts

For instance:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Devel::Peek;

Dump({});
```

Would print the following:

```
SV = IV(0x170fc98) at 0x170fca8
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (TEMP,ROK)
  RV = 0x170fa68
  SV = PVHV(0x1715970) at 0x170fa68
    REFCNT = 1
    FLAGS = (SHAREKEYS)
    ARRAY = 0x0
    KEYS = 0
    FILL = 0
    MAX = 7
    RITER = -1
    EITER = 0x0
```

it seems like **SV = IV(0x170fc98) at 0x170fca8** (a numerical, **IV**, scalar) references the **PVHV** (hash) **SV = PVHV(0x1715970) at 0x170fa68**

I was expecting something like:

```
  SV = PVHV(0x1715970) at 0x170fa68
    REFCNT = 1
    FLAGS = (SHAREKEYS)
    ARRAY = 0x0
    KEYS = 0
    FILL = 0
    MAX = 7
    RITER = -1
    EITER = 0x0
```

Comment: PVHV is not a hash reference. It's a hash.

Comment: @ikegami, typo, sorry. thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each data type in Perl has a common “header” of data that supplies reference counting, etc. The flags in this header determine what type it actually is (e.g. a `PVHV`). So internally a `%hash` is a `PVHV`. The header is followed by other hash-specific fields.

Now what is a `$reference = \%hash`? A reference is a scalar containing a pointer to another data type. This is implemented as the integer field in an `IV`, but the `ROK` flag is set to show that the data isn't an integer but a pointer.

You can only pass scalars to a Perl subroutine, therefore you can only pass a *hash reference*, not a hash itself to `Dump`. As `Dump` prints out whatever scalar you provide, the enclosing reference is also shown.

To understand internal data types in Perl better, I recommend the [*Illustrated Perl Guts*](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/RURBAN/illguts-0.42/index-14.html).

Comment: $reference = \%hash which assign the ref of %hash to the $reference scalar seems ok to me to have the IV header, but my example which is using only {}, I was actually expecting to see only PVHV.

Comment: @naabu That's because `{...}` doesn't create a hash, it constructs a hash reference. It was designed that way because of back-compatibility: collections like `@arrays` or `%hashes` can only contain scalar values, and having `{}` create a reference allows us to write nested literals: `[{foo => 2}, 3, [1, 2, {3 => ["a", "b"]}]]` (`[...]` creates an array reference).

Comment: things were maybe a bit clearer when there were separate IV and RV (reference value) types, but when things were reorganized (for speed and less memory, in 5.10?) they were united.

Comment: @naabu, The above comment should read: That's because `{...}` doesn't **just** create a hash, it **also** constructs a reference to it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, references are always scalars.

The construct `{ ... }` creates an empty hash, then returns a reference to it, which is a scalar.

It's similar to `do { my %anon = ( ... ); \%anon }`.